# AngularJS $routeParams are undefined

Tags: angularjs

I cannot access the *$routeParams* values from my controller.

My angular app is defined as follows;

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module("rbApp", [
        "ngAnimate", "ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ngMessages", "ngRoute", "common.services"    ]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", "$urlMatcherFactoryProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
        $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
        .state("confirmemail", {
            url: "/Confirm_Email?userId",
            templateUrl: "ceForm.html",
            controller: "ceController as ceVm"
        });
    }]);
})();
```

My controller is;

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .controller("ceController", ["$scope", "$state", "$routeParams", "pageContentService", "accountService", "sharedServices", ceController]);

    function ceController($scope, $state, $routeParams, pageContentService, accountService, sharedServices) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.emailConfirmed = false;

        console.log("confirmEmail userId: ", $routeParams.userId);

        if ($routeParams.userId) {
            .
            .
            .
        }

    };
})();
```

However when I pass in a URL like http://example.com?userId=9daa2c41  *$routeParams.userId* is always undefined.

Comment: You're using ui-router so the correct provider is `$stateParams`. `$routeParams` belongs to the `ngRoute` module. I wouldn't recommend mixing the two

Comment: Thanks @Phil that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must load your view in `<ng-view>` in order to get the `$routeParams`. Since `$routeParams` is associated with a `$route`, it doesn't have a value when routing is not used. Same thing applies to your `$stateParams` if you are going that route.